# basic htaccess redirect by with variable move from URL (?id=1e34-2)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Ahoy all, I know these questions have been beaten to death. And even after my hour of research on stack, none of the suggestions or answers I have attempted have worked.

The only thing I am needing to do is....

Take the variable from a URL and redirect to another page (site), inserting that variable accordingly.

Keep in mind the variable can contain letters, dashes, underscores or numbers.

Original

```
/directory-here/a-random-name.php?strPropID=13d3-1
```

and I am redirecting to another domain.

```
http://www.someotherdomain.com/redirect.php?strPropID=13d3-1
```

So now I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^/directory-here/a-random-name.php\?strPropId=(.*)$ http://www.someotherdomain.com/redirect.php?propid=$1 [R=301,L]
```

However the redirect isn't working. What am I doing wrong here? I know it has to be something simple, no?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to match query string using a `RewriteCond` not in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /directory-here/a-random-name.php\?strPropId=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.someotherdomain.com/redirect.php?propid=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hmm unfortunately that doesn't seem to do the trick either. It redirectes to "http://www.someotherdomain.com/directory-here"

Comment: There was a typo (I used `$1` instead of `%1`). Can you try updated rule as **very first rule** in your site root .htaccess